# Calling COM from .NET, is it an example of Adapter pattern?

Tags: .net, design-patterns

If I write a code that calls COM component from .NET, is it an example of Adapter pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW)** functionality in .NET is more an application of the **Proxy** pattern, because the .NET class mirrors the interface of the underlying COM component.

Quote from [Sourcemaking](http://sourcemaking.com):

> Adapter provides a different interface to its subject. Proxy provides the same interface.

**Related resources:**

- [Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx)
- [Proxy Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/proxy)
- [Adapter Design Pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/adapter)

Answer (score 0):

The pinvoke dll generated by Visual studio is already an adapter.